# Knockout Template: Own BindingContext, same Parents

Tags: javascript, templates, knockout.js, binding-context

I'm writing a bindingHandler and want to create a binding-context which has the **same parents/parent-contexts** like the *current* bindingContext. Read: no extra binding-context-hierarchy.

Background: I write a dialog-binding-handler
A dom-node has a dialog-binding like `data-bind="dialog: { childTemplate: 'childTemplateId' }"`
After an click, a **generic dialog-template** gets rendered and attached to body. You also specify a ***child-template*** (= is the desired concrete view), which gets choosen by the generic dialog-template by the **binding-context-variable `$childTemplateName`**.
The child-template should have no clue, that there is an extra layer (= generic dialog template) between it and the level containing the dialog-binding-handler. So `$parent`, `$parent.$parent`, `$parent.$parent.$parent`,... are the same in the child-template and the dom-node having `data-bind="dialog: ..."`.

I want to have an extra binding-context so I can extend it with properties specific for this "dialog-call", so the current binding-context doesn't get polluted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it seems that
`bindingContext.$parentContext.createChildContext(childViewModel);`
works perfecly!
So using `$parentContext` is the (acutally logical) way to go.

*(if I remember correctly I had tried this previously with no success with pervious versions of knockout...but nevermind)*

Answer (score 0):

[`bindingContext.extend`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-controlling-descendant-bindings.html) returns a new bindingContext:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dialog = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var innerBindingContext = bindingContext.extend({
            dialogProperty1: ...
        });
        ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(innerBindingContext, element);

        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};
```

so this should do what you are trying to achieve: a new bindingContext with the same hierarchy and dialog-specific extensions that does not pollute the context outside of your dialog binding.

Comment: I can't use `{controlsDescendantBindings: true }` because the dom-node containing `data-bind: "dialog: ..."` can have contents which have their own bindings... So if I use it an "bound twice" error is thrown.  
However, I found a working solution. But thanks for your efforts!

Comment: It should be the other way around? `controlsDescendantBindings: true` _prevents_ bindings from being bound twice.

Comment: Yes, but my code executes the template on the `click`-event - much later. So actually the children of the dialog-calling-node (bad name, I know) *must* be bound by knockout.

Comment: Gotcha - I missed the part where you used a template, and thought that the child nodes of 'dialog' where the content. I solved this problem pretty much the same way then. [Here's my binding](https://github.com/janfoeh/veiljs/blob/master/veil-knockout.js) in case you're interested.

Comment: Hey thanks, maybe I have a closer look at it.  @code: you pass your viewmodel directly instead of creating a bindingContext - is that intentional? Because you lose your parents this way (if I recall my tests correctly).  
`ko.renderTemplate(veilTemplate, bindingContext.$parentContext.createChildContext(valueAccessor()), {}, overlay.get(0))`  
would help keeping the parents ;)

Comment: The binding is meant to be called with the desired bindingContext as the valueAccessor, such as `veil: $data`. I often found the need to use one of the call sites' parent contexts, and this makes it easier.